# Correspoding gcc option?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, cc

With IBM's cc compiler there is one option -brtl.

cc-brtl .....

This option does the following:-

-brtl     Tells the linkage editor to accept both .so and .a library file types.

I am using gcc compiler now on ubuntu. I want to know what is the corresponding option in gcc to achieve 
the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need that option for `gcc`. The link editor will accept both so and a files by default, with so files being preferred. You can think of `gcc` as having the opposite behaviour to IBM's C compiler: The behaviour without any options is as if you provided `-brtl` to IBM's C compiler, while the option `-static` turns of dynamic linking (and thus causes `gcc` to not take so files into consideration), which is as if you didn't specify `-brtl` to IBM's C compiler.